# Extracting HUE value from specific part of Image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, hsv

I have one image with some structure (rectangle) That all of them are approximately green. I used this code to find a number of those objects in the image and make a contour around them. Their hue value will change over time.  I need to add one code to extract the average of the new hue value in each counter that we detect in the previous step and save them in a new array. I want to find The average hue value inside the mask(or detected contour) after one hour. Thanks for your attention.
[Real image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6UgQ.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\Desktop\Image-1.PNG")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_range = np.array([75, 50, 50])
upper_range = np.array([165, 200, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)

(cnt, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
N2=0
for cont in cnt:
    if cv2.contourArea(cont) > 200:
     # NewVariable[N2,:]=cnt[cont,:]  this line do not work
       N2=N2+1
print("Number of section : ", N2)

rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
count=cv2.drawContours(rgb, cnt, -2, (100, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow('count',count)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please show the input image, not just the mask.

Comment: Hello @fmw42 , I added real image. The color of real image is different in comparison to what python depict since we use BGR to HSV Command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What debugging did you do? Did you list out the areas?

The following works for me after fixing your indentation, contours and drawing commands. I also had to reduce your area threshold to 160 to get all the regions.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("Image-1.PNG")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hue = hsv[:,:,0]
lower_range = np.array([75, 50, 50])
upper_range = np.array([165, 200, 255])
thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)

contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
N2=0
count = img.copy()
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area > 160:
        cv2.drawContours(count, [cnt], 0, (100, 0, 255), 2)
        mask = np.zeros_like(thresh, dtype=np.uint8)
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], 0, (255,255,255), -1)
        ave_hue = np.mean(hue[np.where(mask==255)])
        print("average hue:", ave_hue, "area:", area)
        N2=N2+1
print("Number of section : ", N2)

cv2.imwrite('Image-1-contours.PNG', count)

cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
cv2.imshow('hsv',hsv)
cv2.imshow('count',count)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()Result:
```

[image]

Listing:

```
average hue: 92.6030534351145 area: 227.0
average hue: 92.32921810699588 area: 209.0
average hue: 92.48648648648648 area: 223.5
average hue: 93.0765306122449 area: 165.0
average hue: 92.99335548172758 area: 261.0
average hue: 92.44375 area: 280.0
average hue: 92.94326241134752 area: 244.0
average hue: 92.70454545454545 area: 267.0
average hue: 92.73374613003097 area: 282.5
average hue: 92.90847457627119 area: 255.0
average hue: 93.23026315789474 area: 266.0
average hue: 90.79323308270676 area: 231.0
average hue: 90.33333333333333 area: 253.0
average hue: 90.67405063291139 area: 276.5
average hue: 90.24846625766871 area: 285.0
average hue: 91.09375 area: 278.5
average hue: 90.29577464788733 area: 245.5
average hue: 90.89389067524115 area: 269.5
average hue: 90.12539184952978 area: 278.0
average hue: 90.67202572347267 area: 270.0
average hue: 90.28321678321679 area: 247.0
average hue: 89.54181818181819 area: 239.5
average hue: 89.75565610859728 area: 185.0

Number of section :  23
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I need to extract the average Hue value in each section of the 23 areas. In other words, we need to have 23 average Hue values that each of them belongs to one of that 23 areas.

Comment: For instance, in each area exist approximately 200 pixels. Each pixel has a specific Hue value. I want to get the average of their Hue value. Because in my research the exact Hue value of each section is important, and they are not supposed to be equal. So we used the current code to find the location of each section and then will continue to find the exact average hue value of each section. Thanks for your attention @fmw42

Comment: I have edited my answer to print the average hue for each region along with its pixel area. The way it is done is simply to draw a white filled contour on a black background as a mask and then use np.mean() to compute the average of the hue channel in the region of the mask.

Comment: It is great. Thank you so much. I will start to work with your code and will reach you if I face any problems. All the Best.